# Java Clipboard on Linux (text only), some programs can read it, others can't, why

Tags: java, linux, text, clipboard

When my Java-based application (not a browser-based applet) copies plain text to the system clipboard on Linux, many programs are not able to access the clipboard data, but some are.

Here's the simplest test I could make:

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.*;

public final class PasteTest {
  public static void main (String...  args) {
    String mytext = "This is a test message, testing, 1, 2, 3....";
    StringSelection sel = new StringSelection(mytext);
    Clipboard clip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clip.setContents(sel, null);
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
}
```

While this program is running, File > Paste in OpenOffice (LibreOffice 3.5.7.2) is able to access the text it placed on the system clipboard.  But using File > Paste in Gnome Terminal, Mozilla Thunderbird & Firefox, and many other programs can not.  The Paste option is gray, as if the clipboard is empty.

How can I make my Java program publish plain text to the system clipboard on Linux (testing on Ubuntu 12.04) so all programs can access it?

Comment: What does middle mouse button in Mozilla, or gedit, or terminal do? Usually it pastes from a different X clipboard. Maybe your data goes there?

Comment: It does not go to the X11 selection "clipboard".  The sample code demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK or Sun's JDK?  I've noticed a problem with Java-based programs pasting into the terminal, and I came across changing JDK as a possible solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jedit/+bug/347308).

Answer (score 5):

Your code is fine. Its problem is that it terminates too soon.

Under X window system, the process that puts something on 'clipboard' (that is, the selection named 'clipboard') must stay alive for the copied data to survive. ([Read about active and passive buffers, and notice that selections are of the active kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection)).

While your process runs, that is, `sleep()`s, you can paste the data anywhere. Once it terminates, clipboard goes empty.

This is not special behavior of Java; you can easily reproduce it with `charmap` or any other program you don't mind closing.

I don't know how LibreOffice scored a point in your test. Possibly it was first on your alt+tab list. In my tests, LibreOffice behaved like any other app: 'paste' worked as long as the Java process was alive, and stopped working as the process terminated.

I don't know how to fix it in general case. Running a clipboard manager (that remembers multiple copied items and thus probably owns all of them) might help.

Comment: This is true, but in general it's not the reason. I am seeing the problem right now in Ubuntu 18.04 with a continuously running Java process.

Comment: @StefanReich: In certain circumstances, I was able to reproduce a similar issue with Firefox and Emacs; either may "miss" any new data copied to the clipboard and stick with some previous value. I suspect that this may be a problem inside the X server, rare enough that nobody had resources to repro and fix it.

Comment: Possible. In my case, I can't copy from Java to Gnome Terminal...